# Bash script that displays time on terminal

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, bashrc, manjaro

I wanted to write a bash script that serves like a greeting and show date and time(in terminal), and I ran into some issues. I've done some digging I solved most of the issues. The one and only issue remaining is that when I run the script it doesn't refresh the existing text in the terminal instead it appends the new text to the previous one.

this is a screenshot with the code and the issue.[image]

```
__RAINBOWPALETTE="1"

function __colortext()
{
  echo -e " \e[$__RAINBOWPALETTE;$2m$1\e[0m"
}

 
function echogreen() 
{
  echo -n $(__colortext "$1" "32")
}

function echored() 
{
  echo -n $(__colortext "$1" "31")
}

function echoblue() 
{
  echo -n $(__colortext "$1" "34")
}

function echopurple() 
{
  echo -n $(__colortext "$1" "35")
}

function echoyellow() 
{
  echo -n $(__colortext "$1" "33")
}

function echocyan()
{
  echo -n $(__colortext "$1" "36")
}
printf "\n"
echoblue "Today is: "
echored `date +%a` && echo -n " "
echogreen `date +%d` && echo -n " "
echoyellow `date +%b`
echo " `date +%Y`"


while sleep 1; do
    echoblue "It's "
    echopurple `date +%r`\\c
done

printf "\n\n"
```

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Since it is a greeting maybe you may simply add a `clear` and rewrite all in the cycle... and maybe read a key to exit form the while... BTW there are commands to save the current terminal XY position and to _jump_ back to them...

Comment: @Hastur Thank you for your answer. That works too, but what I want is to be able to use the terminal even thought the loop is still going.

Comment: You are welcome. If in the same line you may try `printf`, give it a look to `printf "BBBBB" ; printf "\r"; printf "AAA\n"`.  The `\n` is for the newline... the `\r` is to start again the line... if you miss the `\n` you will not see any `B` but your prompt string... in which you can put the time and date (search for it). But it will be updated only with a new prompt output... That means when you press enter and the command _ends_.

Comment: @Hastur I kind of get what it does. I'll play with it a little and see if I'll get the result i want. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ad nauseam: do not put it in your `~/.bashrc`, put it in another file  (e.g. `~/.mygreetings`) and call it from the `.bashrc`. You will have a more clean `.basshrc` and you will bring to your next computer easily... `if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
` change the names...

Comment: @Hastur OK! I will seperate the scripts and I'll tell you what happens.

Comment: @Hastur It didn't work despite separating the scripts and using the "printf..." way.

Comment: search for ansi escape sequences to control cursor position with arrow keys, this way you can script ui without refreshing whole screen

Comment: @Plund3r3r Hi, I reread with some seconds more one of your comments. To have a clock always working on your terminal can be nice, but even source of problems when you will start to use your terminal output (you cannot know in advance the _race contest_ between your printing operations and the output of the other programs). It was a used practice to put it in the prompt string.. e.g. try in a new terminal `PS1="[\u@\h \D{%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S}]\$ "`. You can custom it with colors... In general to "use the terminal meanwhile", you can execute the script with a final `&`: `/bin/bash myscript.sh &`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this; add `\r` just before `It's`

```
while sleep 1; do
    echoblue "\rIt's "
    echopurple `date +%r`\\c
done
```

Comment: It works perfectly, there is one small issue is that I can't type commands in my terminal. It just shows the clock working but not the prompt.

Comment: That is most likely harder to accomplish, and likely not possible with bash-scripting. You might need to include it in Bash itself, e.g. in the code to read input at the prompt, while updating the prompt once a second. For one thing; it needs to be "atomic" (not interruptable).

Comment: To learn more bash, got to https://tldp.org/ and look up and study the Bash guides

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the good help!